# Can I use parts of html template of a component in different part in parent component

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vuex

I have a component which returns locations, then places, then hotels one after her other but I want these in 3 different parts like they show in tabs.

**component code:**

```
<template>

<li class="col-xs-12" :id="location.id">

    <p class="col-xs-3">{{location.name}} - Days : </p>
    <div class="col-xs-2"><input type="text" v-model="location.days"></div>
    <div class="col-xs-4">
        <!--            {{hotelset(location.id,hotels)}}-->
        <!--            {{typeof (hotels)}}{{index}}-->
        <v-select v-model="hotelselect[location.id]" name="addhotel" label="title"
            @input="addtohotel(index,location.id)" :value="non" :options=hoteloptions[location.id] />
        <!--{{hoteloptions}}-->
        <!--{{$props}}-->
    </div>

    <button @click="remove" class="col-xs-3 btn btn-danger">Remove</button>
    <div></div>

    <div class="col-xs-12" v-for="day in parseInt(location.days)" :key="day">
        Day {{day}}-
        {{preselect(day,defaultt,location.id,place)}}

        <v-select v-model="days[day]" name="addplaceloc" label="title" @input="addtoplaces(day,location.id)"
            :value="defaultt" :options="localplace[location.id][day]" multiple />
        <!--{{localplace[location.id][day]}}-->
        <div v-for="(placeinfo, index) in objj[location.id]['day-'+day]['place']">Place: {{placeinfo['title']}}:

            <label>From:</label><input type="text"
                v-model="objj[location.id]['day-'+day]['place'][index]['from_time']">
            <label>To:</label><input type="text" v-model="objj[location.id]['day-'+day]['place'][index]['to_time']">
            <label>Remark:</label><input type="text"
                v-model="objj[location.id]['day-'+day]['place'][index]['remark']">
            <button @click="run"> yess</button>
        </div>

    </div>

</li>

<!--@click="remove"-->
```

in above code there are 2 `v-select` and 1 input listed one after the other as they are dependent to each other but I want it in different tabs in parent vue file. How to achieve it? tabs have its own style and html structure.

Comment: Where are you having problems? Assuming Bootstrap4.3 there's [documentation on tabs](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/components/navs/#tabs) and [tabs javascript behavior](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/components/navs/#javascript-behavior)

Comment: i want to use parts of component in different parts of parent

Comment: That's what components are for. Extract them to their own separate components, and then you can use those where you need them.

Answer (score 0):

As @muka.gergely said, the only way to re-use HTML is to break it off into separate components.